# How can I create the `framework.mrb` file to generate my own genesis file?

Tags: blockchain, aptos

I try to construct my own private Aptos network.

To do this, I'm following the guidelines in ["Generating genesis" document](https://aptos.dev/tools/aptos-cli/use-cli/cli-genesis).

In this document, "Building the Aptos Framework" part seems like wrong, because provided commands in the document does not build the `framework.mrb` file.

My try is using the command `cargo build --release --package aptos-framework`. This command builds `aptos-framework` file in the `target/release` directory.

However, when I executed the `aptos -- genesis generate-genesis --local-repository-dir .` command, it produced an error like "Unable to read file './framework.mrb". So, I changed the name of the previously created `aptos-framework` file to `framework.mrb`. Then, it produced an error like "exceeded max sequence length: 3487268175". My guess is that I tried with a different file.

So, my question is, how can I create a `framework.mrb` file to generate my own genesis file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

To get `framework.mrb`, you first build `aptos-framework`.

To do this, on the `aptos-core` repository, do the below command:

```
cargo run --package aptos-framework
```

Then, you can find a `aptos-framework` binary file in the `target/debug` directory.

Using this binary, you can create a `.mrb` file.

```
./aptos-framework release
```

Then, in the same directory, you can find a `head.mrb` file. Change the name of this file to `framework.mrb`.